# Reading CSV data with oleDBConnection into a C# DataSet and adding column headings

Tags: c#, csv, dataset

I have a .csv file that I am reading into C# via an OLEDBConnection.  I am loading this into a DataSet.  This step works fine.  My data in the .csv file does not have any heading data/column headings.  I want to add column headings to my DataSet in C# rather than directly into the .csv file.  If I try to add column headings, then it just creates a new column on the end of the data, however I want to add the heading to the existing columns that already have data in it rather than create a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the column using index and the change the name

```
DataTable table = your datatable;
table.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Foo";
```

Comment: Thank you that now enables me to add a column heading. However adding the column headings means that I now lose my first row of data as the column headings are overwriting what was my first row.  I obviously need to keep all data intact and just add the column headings before the first data row.

Comment: Do you have something similar to this in your code "table.Columns.Add" Can you please share that part of the code. It is a common practice to read the first line and assign the values as column names. I think you are doing something similar

Comment: No, I've not used tables.Columns.Add as that appends a new column to the existing columns.  I've used as you suggested table.Columns[0].ColumnName and this correctly labels the first column, but in doing so removes the first row of data.  I will post the code in a new comment.

Comment: using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var query = "SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "]";

                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {

                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                  
                }

                dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Column1";
                dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Column2";               
            }

Comment: Ok make sure you have HDR=No in your connection string.